# Injection of autowired dependencies failed; Could not autowire field

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm a newbie in Spring MVC and hibernate, I've been in a slump so i hope you guys can help.
     Everytime i run i get the exception error in creating bean. i can't seem to find the correct answer in the internet, 
       I can't seem to find what i'm missing here. I hope you guys can help me.
        My Context.xml

```
           <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
            xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
            xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

            <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

            <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
            <annotation-driven />

            <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
            <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

            <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
                <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
                <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
            </beans:bean>


                <context:annotation-config/>
                <context:component-scan base-package="com.test.cedric." />
                <beans:bean id="departmentController" class="com.test.cedric.controller.DepartmentController" />
                 <beans:bean id="departmentDaoImpl" class="com.test.cedric.dao.DepartmentDaoImpl">

            </beans:bean>
                 <beans:bean id="departmentServiceImpl" class="com.test.cedric.service.DepartmentServiceImpl">

            </beans:bean>

        </beans:beans>

        <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
            "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
            "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

    My hibernate.cfg.xml
        <hibernate-configuration>
            <session-factory>
                <!-- Database connection settings -->
                <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
                <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test1</property>
                <property name="connection.username">root</property>
                <property name="connection.password"></property>

                <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
                <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

                <!-- SQL dialect -->
                <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

                <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
                <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

                <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
                <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

                <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
                <property name="show_sql">false</property>

                <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>

                <mapping resource="com.test.cedric.model.Department"/>


            </session-factory>
        </hibernate-configuration>
```

My Service Code

```
         package com.test.cedric.service;

        import java.util.List;

        import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
        import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
        import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

        import com.test.cedric.dao.DepartmentDao;
        import com.test.cedric.dao.DepartmentDaoImpl;
        import com.test.cedric.model.Department;

        @Service

        public class DepartmentServiceImpl implements DepartmentService{

            @Autowired
            DepartmentDao dDao;
            @Transactional 
            @Override
            public void addDept(Department department) {
                dDao.addDept(department);
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void delDept(Department department) {
                dDao.delDept(department);
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void editDept(Department department) {
                dDao.editDept(department);
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public List<Department> getAllDept() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return dDao.getAll();
            }

            @Override
            public Department getDeptById(int dept_id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }


        }
```

My DAO

```
            package com.test.cedric.dao;

        import java.util.List;

        import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
        import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
        import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

        import com.test.cedric.model.Department;

        @Repository
        public class DepartmentDaoImpl implements DepartmentDao {

            @Autowired
            SessionFactory sessionFactory;
            @Override
            public void addDept(Department department) {
                sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(department);

            }

            @Override
            public void delDept(Department department) {
                sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(department);

            }

            @Override
            public void editDept(Department department) {
                sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(department);
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            public List<Department> getAll() {
                sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("From Department");
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("From Department").list();
            }

            @Override
            public Department getDeptById(int dept_id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Please post the exception stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have the following

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.cedric." />
<beans:bean id="departmentController" class="com.test.cedric.controller.DepartmentController" />
<beans:bean id="departmentDaoImpl" class="com.test.cedric.dao.DepartmentDaoImpl">
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="departmentServiceImpl" class="com.test.cedric.service.DepartmentServiceImpl">
</beans:bean>
```

The `component-scan` scans the package you've declared and if it finds the annotations `@Component`, `@Service`, `@Repository`, `@Controller`, or `@Configuration` will create a bean instance for you. As such, your own bean declarations above are redundant. Get rid of them.

Second, unless you aren't showing it, you don't actually have a `SessionFactory` bean which is a candidate for autowiring. The `<session-factory>` element in your **hibernate configuration** has nothing to do with the Spring context beans. If you want to connect the two, you can use

```
<bean
    id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation">    
        <value>
            classpath:location_of_config_file/hibernate.cfg.xml
        </value>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            ...    
        </props>    
    </property>

</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you've supplied us, it looks like you're missing a bean configuration for sessionFactory. Each @Autowire annotation that you use has to correspond to a Spring bean.  So in your Context.xml, you'd need to add something like:

```
<beans:bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    ... bean configuration properties ...
</beans:bean>
```

The AnnotationSessionFactoryBean might not be the actual bean that you use -- there's a bunch of ways to do it, and you can search around to figure out what you want to do.  But you definitely need to add a definition for a bean called "sessionFactory".